# In Spark Streaming, can we store data (hashmap) in Executor memory

Tags: caching, apache-spark, hashmap, streaming, executor

I want to maintain a cache (HashMap) in Spark Executors memory (long lived cache) so that all tasks running on the executor (at different times) can do a lookup there and also be able to update the cache.

Is this possible in Spark streaming?

Comment: My requirement is I have a remote key-value data store (small - total size about 50MB). This data may get updated once in a hour with just one change in one hour like new key-value pair added, deleted or changed. My spark streaming jobs need to lookup this store very frequently. So I want to store this key-value data in nodes/executors cache, so that all jobs running on that executor at all times can lookup this data and also refresh it once in 10 minutes. Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a way to store custom data structures permanently on executors. My suggestion here is to use some external caching system (like Redis, Memcached or even ZooKeeper in some cases). You can further connect to that system using such methods like `foreachPartition` or `mapPartitions` while processing RDD/DataFrame to reduce the number of connections to 1 connection per partition.

The reason of why this would work is that i.e. both Redis and Memcached are in-memory storages so there will be no overhead of spilling data to disk.

The two other ways to distribute some state across executors are Accumulators and Broadcast variables. For Accumulators all executors can write into it but reading can be performed only by driver. For Broadcast variable you write it only once on driver and then distribute it as a read-only data structure to executors. Both cases doesn't work for you so the described solution is the only possible way that I can see here.

Comment: As somebody suggested earlier (I dont know how that post got deleted) can we use "updateStateByKey" for this where the state would be the key-value hashmap. What I know is Spark streaming automatically persists this data and can be used across batches. Is this feasible ? long lived ?

Comment: Of course you can use `updateStateByKey` or even `mapWithState`. But this is a specific step in Stream computation. But in order to do this you have to transform your stream into stream of key-value pairs. This is completely feasible and long lived. The main idea of this method is that state is shared between different stream batches but not across executors. This state update requires additional step for your stream and can't be performed as a side effect of another operation (unlike approach I described). But maybe it would work for you. Depends on a particular use case.

Comment: Any pointers to some code that use updateStateByKey or mapWithState so that I get clear understanding of this ???